# Problems binding JTable selectedRow to JTextField (org.jdesktop.beansbinding)

Tags: java, beans-binding

I have a Java Swing application and want to bind the selected row of a JTable to a JTextField. My binding looks as follows:

```
    BeanProperty<JTable, Integer> tableBeanProperty = BeanProperty.create("selectedRow");
    BeanProperty<JTextField, String> textFieldProperty = BeanProperty.create("text");
    Binding<JTable, Integer, JTextField, String> binding = Bindings.createAutoBinding(UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, table1, tableBeanProperty, field1, textFieldProperty);
    binding.bind();
```

The text field is filled one time at the beginning with '-1', because no row is selected. If I click on a row, there is no update of the text field.
One ugly workaround is to call the `unbind()` and `bind()` method in the mouse listener of the table. But I think there is something missing during my binding.

Maybe one of you has an idea.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says, that "selectedElement" can be used for this purpose. With this property, it works without the ugly `unbind()` and `bind()`.

Now the code looks as follows:

```
BeanProperty<JTable, MyObject> tableBeanProperty = BeanProperty.create("selectedElement");
BeanProperty<JTextField, String> textFieldProperty = BeanProperty.create("text");
Binding<JTable, MyObject, JTextField, String> binding = Bindings.createAutoBinding(UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, table1, tableBeanProperty, field1, textFieldProperty);
binding.bind();
```

To convert "MyObject" to a "String", I added a converter to the binding.